# Python: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql

I am not able to insert a list of strings in mysql database. I keep getting the error "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement". Is there something wrong I am doing

```
rowval = ['1.0', '2.0','1.5', '1.6', '', '.85']
query_string = 'INSERT INTO table(tech) VALUES (%s)'
cursor.execute(query_string, rowval)
cursor.close()
database.commit()
```

Comment: You only have one placeholder, but six values. Did you want to [`executemany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany)?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, tried execute many too but still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the blank value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `rowval = ['1.0', '2.0','1.5', '1.6', '', '.85']`, you should have something like this in your `query_string`:

```
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Or depending how you setup your database your can do something like this:

```
query_string = 'INSERT INTO database.<TABLE_NAME> (parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5, parameter6) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
```

or in your case if you wan't to inser into only one column you would do
it like this:

```
value_for_tech = <SOME_VALUE>
query_string = 'INSERT INTO DB.<TABLE_NAME> (tech) VALUES (%s)'
cursor.execute(query_string, value_for_tech)
```

folowing the rules of sql query building:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Comment: but i dont no how many values I can have, that can change so how can i manage that?

Comment: @edcoder How does your table `tech` look like, do you have a schema? What does for instance '.85' represent?

Comment: tech(varchar(10) is a column in my table. So I am trying to insert those values into the column

Comment: statvalues is the name of the table

Comment: Hi @cheshire, so the issue was because of the blank value. I was able to fix the issue as soon as I removed the blank value

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n

Answer (score 0):

According this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp) you can insert multiple list of list as multiple rows into MySQL:

```
rowval = ['1.0', '2.0','1.5', '1.6', '', '.85']
data = list(map(lambda x: [x], rowval))
print(data)
"""
should be [['1.0'], ['2.0'], ['1.5'], ['1.6'], [''], ['.85']]
"""

query_string = 'INSERT INTO table(tech) VALUES (%s)'
cursor.execute(query_string, data)
cursor.close()
database.commit()
```

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n